# How to create a IWICImagingFactory instance in winapi-rs

Tags: winapi, rust

I try this way,

```
    let mut factory: *mut IWICImagingFactory = std::ptr::null_mut();
    let hr = unsafe {
        CoCreateInstance(
            &CLSID_WICImagingFactory,
            std::ptr::null_mut(),
            CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
            &IWICImagingFactory::uuidof(),
            &mut factory as *mut *mut _ as *mut *mut _,
        )
    };
    assert!(factory.is_null());
```

but the factory pointer still is null, the hr is -2147221008, I don't know what that means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error code `-2147221008` (or `0x800401F0`) [translates](https://www.magnumdb.com/search?q=-2147221008) to `CO_E_NOTINITIALIZED`. The documentation for [`CoInitializeEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-coinitializeex) explains why you'd receive this error:

> You need to initialize the COM library on a thread before you call any of the library functions [...]. Otherwise, the COM function will return CO_E_NOTINITIALIZED.

To instantiate an `IWICImagingFactory` interface implementation you'll have to initialize COM on the calling thread first:

```rust
let hr = unsafe { CoInitialize(std::ptr::null_mut()) };
// Handle errors
```

---

As a note, unless you have a specific reason to use the [winapi](https://crates.io/crates/winapi) crate, go with the [windows](https://crates.io/crates/windows) crate instead. It makes COM programming in Rust *a lot* more convenient.